# Grails with JqGrid inline edit with List()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, grails, jqgrid

I am working on setting up JqGrid with Grails and have in-line editing working.  I have a drop-down box appear when the user selects a specific cell.

I want to populate this drop-down list from a table but am having trouble connecting the pieces together.  Here is the code i have so far...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#task_list").jqGrid({
          ...

          colModel:[
          {name:'foo', editable:true, edittype:'select', editOptions:{values: ${com.project.inf.Domain.list()}}},
          ...
```

The ${com.project.inf.Domain.list()} creates a list of comma-delimited items, which I want to be displayed as options in the drop-down.  However, it seems editOptions only accepts name:value pairs.  Is there a simple way to re-format the List() so it is accepted?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation and reading of tutorials, I found the solution to this problem.  I had to create a custom controller action and use the "dataUrl" option to use it as follows:

```
{name:'foo', width:100, editable:true, edittype:'select', 
editoptions: {dataUrl:'${createLink(controller:"bar",action:"listAsSelect")}'}}
```

With the following as the listAsSelect action in the "bar" controller:

```
def listAsSelect={
    def lst = Bar.findAll()

    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("<select>")
    lst.each{
        buf.append("<option value=\"${it.id}\">")
        buf.append(it.toString())
        buf.append("</option>")
    }
    buf.append("</select>")

    render buf.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo resolví asi:

**View:**

{name:'listaDinamica',width:90, editable: true,
 editrules:required:true},edittype:'select',

editoptions:{value:'${slcustomer}'}},

**Controller:**

class TablaModeloController {

```
TablaModeloService tms=new TablaModeloService()
def slcustomer= tms.llenaClientes()
def sl=Customer.list()

def index() {}
```

...

**Service:**

class TablaModeloService {

def llenaClientes(){

def clientes=''

Customer.list().each{

clientes+=it.id+":"+it.firstName+";"

}

clientes=clientes[0..-2]

return clientes
    }

}

Trabaja perfecto